# Passing multiple values in QueryString to a new page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have looked for other solutions here on StackOverflow but i cant seem to figure it out.
I have this linkbutton in a datagrid:

```
    <asp:LinkButton 
        ID="lnkname" runat="server"
        Text='<%#Eval("Titel") %>'
        PostBackUrl='<%#"Details.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID").toString()%>'
        CausesValidation="false">
    </asp:LinkButton>
```

and this is the paramater:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTitel" DefaultValue="*" Name="Titel" 
PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />
```

I want to take the ID value to the next page : details.aspx but i get the following error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I know it has something to do with ID being a INT but I cant figure out how to fix it.

NOTE: I do it in VB.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in casting it to string

```
+Eval("ID").toString()
```

use this

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "Details.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID").ToString() %>'
```

The `.toString()` should be `ToString()`

### Edit 1

Or you can use

```
Try using a HyperLinkField
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
                 HeaderText="Client IP"
                 DataNavigateUrlFields="IP"
                 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Details.aspx?id={0}"
                 DataTextField="ID"
                 DataTextFormatString="{0}"/>
```

Comment: Shamefully I cant give you a rep+ as I am a starter @ stack overflow... But I thank you very much! Its working fine now.

Thank you for your time,

Kind regards

Comment: kindly put your new html of `asp link button`

Comment: You are welcome and there is nothing wrong for being starter :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass multiple parameters then you can use `&` between them For example

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "Details.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")+"&x=50" %>'
```

**Important**

Whenever you are concatenating(joining) a variable of any type like `Eval("ID")` value to a string like `"Details.aspx?ID="`, You do not need to write `ToString()` for casting becasue concatenation does this casting implicitly (automatically). I am sure about this behaviour for `C#` and `VB.NET`

So you could write simply

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "Details.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID") %>'
```